# WINapi. Can't erase background of window with ellipse

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm just trying to draw an ellipse:

```
case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(parentWindow, &ps);
        Ellipse(hdc, x, y, width, height);
        EndPaint(parentWindow, &ps);
```

, and then erase it with drawing a new ellipse with some new parameters every second using timer:

```
case WM_CREATE:
        SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, NULL);
        break;
case WM_TIMER:
        x += 5;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
```

But ellipses are not erased and layered:

[image: Ellipses]

However, i tried to trace WM_ERASEBKGND and it really is sent every InvalidateRect.

Full code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>


TCHAR szWindowClass[] = TEXT("CreateThreadWindow");
TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("CreateThreadExample");

BOOL InitWindow(HINSTANCE, int);
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HWND parentWindow;
MSG msg;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if (!InitWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow))
        return FALSE;
    BOOL bRet;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, (HWND)NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (bRet == -1)
            return FALSE;
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASS wndClass;
    memset(&wndClass, 0, sizeof(wndClass));
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    return RegisterClass(&wndClass);
}

BOOL InitWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    parentWindow = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szAppName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        300, 0, 600, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(parentWindow, nCmdShow);
    return TRUE;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    static int x = 0, y = 0, width = 200, height = 100;
    switch (message) {
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        _RPT1(0, "%s\n", "erase");
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        Ellipse(hdc, x, y, width, height);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        x += 5;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't erase the background, and you don't provide a brush. My guess is that you need to do one of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't erasing anything. It's just drawing an ellipse at the specified coordinates. The previously-drawn ellipse is still there.

You mention the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, but there are two reasons why that isn't working for you:

1. In your window procedure (`WndProc`), you handle the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message explicitly, which means that it doesn't get passed to the default window procedure (`DefWindowProc`). A better way to write your window procedure would be the following:

   ```
   LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
   {
       static int x = 0, y = 0, width = 200, height = 100;
       switch (message) {
       case WM_ERASEBKGND:
       {
           _RPT1(0, "%s\n", "erase");
           break;
       }
       case WM_PAINT:
       {
           PAINTSTRUCT ps;
           HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
           Ellipse(hdc, x, y, width, height);
           EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
           return 0;
       }
       case WM_CREATE:
       {
           SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, NULL);
           break;
       }
       case WM_TIMER:
       {
           x += 5;
           InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
           return 0;
       }
       case WM_DESTROY:
       {
           PostQuitMessage(0);
           return 0;
       }
       default:
           break;
       }

       return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wparam, lparam);
   }
   ```

   Now, the default window procedure gets called every time, unless you explicitly `return` from inside of a `case` label.
2. When you register your window class (inside of `MyRegisterClass`), you zero all fields of the [`WNDCLASS` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576.aspx) and then explicitly initialize a couple of them. You *don't* explicitly initialize the `hbrBackground` field, so it is being set to 0. And when `hbrBackground` is 0,

   > When this member is `NULL`, an application must paint its own background whenever it is requested to paint in its client area. To determine whether the background must be painted, an application can either process the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message or test the `fErase` member of the `PAINTSTRUCT` structure filled by the `BeginPaint` function.

   This means that the default window procedure isn't doing anything in response to the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message because you didn't give your window a background brush.

   You will either need to set `hbrBackground` to something like `COLOR_WINDOW + 1`, or you will need to add code to your `WM_ERASEBKGND` message handler to erase the window's background yourself.

Or, perhaps an even better option would be to forget about the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message altogether, as many Windows programmers do, because this two-step erase-and-paint approach tends to cause flicker. Leave the `hbrBackground` field set to NULL, don't do anything in response to the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, and do your erasing at the top of the `WM_PAINT` handler:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    // Erase background of entire client area.
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
    FillRect(hdc, &rcClient, reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW+1));

    // Do normal drawing.
    Ellipse(hdc, x, y, width, height);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Erasing background in WM_PAINT can still create flicker, unless you use a memory DC for offscreen painting. I suggest using [buffered paint API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773257(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Obviously it does not solve all flickering problems, but it goes a long way towards solving the problem in the most common cases. If you need a bigger gun, they are certainly available, but I rarely if ever need one when developing standard Windows applications. And in 90% of the cases I see where someone has flickering, the solution is to fix the broken painting code, not to start buffering everything indiscriminately.